# SonarQube Analysing a specific File

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, continuous-integration, sonarqube, continuous-deployment

I am attempting to use sonarqube to analyse a specific file (filename.ts) in an azure devops git repository which I want to run daily.

So far I have established:

1. ```
   A sonarqube project and generated project token in our sonarqube saas.
   ```
2. ```
   Created a CD release pipeline in Azure DevOps including the predefined sonarqube tasks:

       *    prepare analysis on sonarqube (unclear to me how I configure this)
       *    run code analysis (looks as if this doesn't require configuration)
       *    publish quality gate (same belief here that it doesn't require configuration)
   ```
3. ```
   Identified the repository where the file exists in the azure repo.
   ```
4. ```
   I have also discovered the artifact name that the repo's CI pipeline generates.
   ```
5. ```
   Found a preconfigured sonarqube service connection in Azure DevOps.
   ```

Where I am now scratching my head is determining these points:

```
a.  How to tell my CD pipeline where the file is in the azure repo. Should I point it to the file in the Repo? Or should i take it from the CI artifact?

b.  Would the sonarqube project require further configuration so to see the file?
```

I feel like there a few more pieces to this puzzle. Can anyone point me on the right path please including anything else I might not have envisaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if the preconfigured sonarqube service connection point to your sonarqube host.

Go to `Project settings` in azure devops-->`Service connections`-->Select the preconfigured `sonarqube service connection`-->Click `Edit`-->check if the `Server Url` point to your sonarqube host url.

If the preconfigured sonarqube service connection points to a different a sonarqube host. You need to create a new sonarqube service connection for your sonarqube host.

**Analyse a specific file**:

You can set the `sonar.inclusions` property to only analyse a specific file. See below diagram. Please check the [document Narrowing the Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) for more information.

[image]

You can configure the `sonar.inclusions` property in the `Additional Properties` field of Prepare Analysis Configuration task in your release pipeline.

[image]

Or you can also set the `sonar.inclusions` property  in your SonarQube project UI.

> To use exclusions to analyze only the specified subset(s) of files in sonar.sources, go to Project Settings > General Settings > Analysis Scope > Files.
>
> - Source File Inclusions
> - Test File Inclusions

Comment: Thank you @Levi, I followed your detailed response. I did encounter a missing component: "ERROR: Cannot find module 'typescript'". Is this something I can install in a separate step within the Azure CD Release Pipeline?

Comment: Hello @Levi, I solved the error by adding a task to install the typescript npm. It was a simple bash script "npm install typescript". Thanks for your assistance, I will mark you as the accepted answer.